# App script to update the data changes to multiple sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I made a script to combine data from Sheet1 and Sheet2 into Sheet "Master".

If there is a data change in the "Master" sheet, I write the script to update the data changes to each sheet.

[image: Sheet1 and Sheet2]

[My Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Aa1ddDdaNw4Tm_tGNN5jnGzMeHJM_VAOHIFBZv0dzCM/edit#gid=0)

```
//combine data from multiple sheets
function MergeSheets() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var data = null;
  var RetrieveSheet = null;
  var PasteSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Master");
  var sheets = ['Sheet1','Sheet2'];
  PasteSheet.getRange(2,1,PasteSheet.getLastRow(),PasteSheet.getLastColumn()).clear();

  for (var i =0; i<sheets.length; i++){
    RetrieveSheet = ss.getSheetByName(sheets[i]);
    if (RetrieveSheet.getName() != 'Master'){
      data = RetrieveSheet.getRange(2,1,RetrieveSheet.getLastRow(),RetrieveSheet.getLastColumn()); 
      data.copyTo(PasteSheet.getRange(parseInt(PasteSheet.getLastRow())+1,1));
    }
  }
}

//update data changes to each sheets
function updateBasedSheet(){
  var master = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Master');
  var valueMaster = master.getRange(2, 1, master.getLastRow(), master.getLastColumn()).getValues();
  var sheet1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  var sheet2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet2');
  var dataSheet1 = valueMaster.filter( function(item){
    return item[2] === 'Sheet1';
  });

  var dataSheet2 = valueMaster.filter( function(item){
    return item[2] === 'Sheet2';
  });

  sheet1.getRange(2, 1, dataSheet1.length, dataSheet1[0].length).setValues(dataSheet1);
  sheet2.getRange(2, 1, dataSheet2.length, dataSheet2[0].length).setValues(dataSheet2);
}
```

But, my code is still no simple. The problem is when I have 100 sheets, I have to write over and over:

[image: this]

Comment: It looks that this question is more about programming that about using Google Apps Script editor / Google Sheets but IMHO it's not yet clear enough to migrate it to another site in the network. I suggest you to checkout the How to ask guidelines of [so] and [codereview.se].

Comment: Related: [Functions — reusable blocks of code](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/JavaScript/Building_blocks/Functions)

Comment: my problem has been solved, thanks sir

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My question has been solved. I modified my code like this :

```
//Remark sheet
function remark_sheet(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheets = ss.getSheets().reduce(function(acc, elem){
    if (elem.getSheetName() != "Master") {
       acc.push(elem);
       }
       return acc;
  },[]);

  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++){
      var lastR = sheets[i].getRange(1, 2).getDataRegion(SpreadsheetApp.Dimension.ROWS).getLastRow();
      sheets[i].getRange("C2:C").clearContent();
      sheets[i].getRange("C2:C"+lastR).setValue(sheets[i].getSheetName());
  }
}

//combine data from multiple sheets
function MergeSheets() {
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var data = [];
  var masterSheet = ss.getSheetByName("Master");

  var sheets = ss.getSheets().reduce(function(acc, elem){
    if (elem.getSheetName() != "Master") {
       acc.push(elem);
       }
       return acc;
  },[]);  // here I get all sheets obj  excluding master sheet as array [sheet, sheet, ...]

  masterSheet.getRange(2,1,masterSheet.getLastRow(),masterSheet.getLastColumn()).clearContent();

  data = sheets.reduce(function(arr, sheet){
     arr = arr.concat(sheet.getDataRange().getValues());
     return arr;
  },[]).filter(function(row){
   return row[0] != "No";
  });

  masterSheet.getRange(2, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
}

//update data changes to each sheets
function updateBasedSheet(){
  var app = SpreadsheetApp;
  var ss = app.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var master = ss.getSheetByName('Master');
  var valueMaster = master.getRange(2, 1, master.getLastRow(), master.getLastColumn()).getValues();

  var sheets = ss.getSheets().reduce(function(acc, elem){
    if (elem.getSheetName() != "Master") {
       acc.push(elem);
       }
       return acc;
  },[]);

  for (var i = 0; i < sheets.length; i++){
    var data = valueMaster.filter( function(item){
      return item[2] === sheets[i].getSheetName();
     });
     sheets[i].getRange("A2:C").clearContent();
     sheets[i].getRange(2, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
  }

}
```

Comment: It's very likely that your answer will be better received in you briefly describe the changes you made to the original script.